# Блокирование спойлера на css

Tags: html, css3

Делаю *css*-спойлер, почти полностью подстроил его под себя, осталась одна проблема с блокировкой на закрытие спойлера, когда нажимаешь в область, находящуюся внутри него.

Вот [сам спойлер, как он выглядит сейчас](http://gtascript.ru/test.htm).

Как видно, если нажать на поле ввода, то спойлер закрывается

Помогите каким-нибудь способом его заблокировать в этот момент, может быть через *JS* и *onclick*, или *css* можно как-нибудь настроить

прошу помочь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как это чудо работает? Костыльная магия? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если устроит, могу предложить [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/omuojL17/).

```css
.spoiler_open, .spoiler_close {
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background: #3B3B3B;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px dotted #BFBFBF;
    text-indent: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
}
.spoiler_close {
    display: none;
}
.spoiler_desc {
    display: none;
    background: #D1D1D1;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.spoiler_open:target {
    display: none;
}
.spoiler_open:target + .spoiler_close,
.spoiler_open:target + .spoiler_close + .spoiler_desc {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#spoiler-open-1" id="spoiler-open-1" class="spoiler_open">Spoiler 1</a>
<a href="#spoiler-close-1" id="spoiler-close-1" class="spoiler_close">Spoiler 1</a>
<div class="spoiler_desc">
 <p>Description 1</p>
    <p><input type="text" value="some_val 1"></p>
</div>

<a href="#spoiler-open-2" id="spoiler-open-2" class="spoiler_open">Spoiler 2</a>
<a href="#spoiler-close-2" id="spoiler-close-2" class="spoiler_close">Spoiler 2</a>
<div class="spoiler_desc">
 <p>Description 2</p>
    <p><input type="text" value="some_val 2"></p>
</div>

<a href="#spoiler-open-3" id="spoiler-open-3" class="spoiler_open">Spoiler 3</a>
<a href="#spoiler-close-3" id="spoiler-close-3" class="spoiler_close">Spoiler 3</a>
<div class="spoiler_desc">
 <p>Description 3</p>
    <p><input type="text" value="some_val 3"></p>
</div>
```